# With field extension is odd the nonsquare element in $GF(p)$ is also a nonsquare in $GF(p^e)$ where $p$ is odd prime

Tags: finite-fields, extension-field

I just want to know how to get this little thing, for $\theta\in GF(p)$ is a nonsquare element where $p$ is an odd prime, $\theta\in GF(p^e)$ is also a nonsquare element since $e$ is odd.
I hope someone can hint me in caculation of finite field, and I think field extension theorem will be used.

Comment: What do you mean by "this little thing?"

Comment: I use "this little thing" as my habits, sorry for this ambiguity. "this little thing" is just the anwer or hint of my question.

Comment: The field extension method is to look at $F_p[x]/(x^2-\theta)$, what is it, how many elements, what happens if it is a subfield of $F_{p^e}$

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109994/11619) is about the case $e=3$. As fas as I can tell, all the answers (including the one given as a comment) generalize to any odd $e$.

Comment: thanks for your help. ~~~///(^v^)\\\~~~

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $a\in GF(p)$ is a square iff  $a^{(p-1)/2}=1$

Comment: you mean $GF(p^e)$ ?

Comment: I get the $a^{(p^e-1)/2} = -1 (mod p)$ but I have no idea what's going on. Do I get the  wrong direction from your hint to get the answer?